# Custom button on a row in UITableView?

Tags: button, uitableview

I would like to add a custom button (checked/unchecked) to each row of the UITableView. Should I use UITableViewCell for this purpose?

Also, if I want the same look and feel for each UITableViewCell, should I create multiple cells and apply the same properties to each cell or is there any trick to repeat the process?

I will be using IB for this purpose.

Thanks,
Amy (Novice)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you have a look at the TableViewSuite sample project.  It has a lot of useful example information for configuring UITableViews, including an example of subclassing UITableViewCell.  Here's a link:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableViewSuite/index.html